# how to run testng.xml multiple times with different testdata from excel

Tags: xml, excel, selenium, testng

I want to know how we can run a testng xml multiple times with different set of data.
i am fetching data from excel files based on testcaseno parameter present in testng xml and it is working as expected. now i want to expand my testing by using same xml file for multiple set of data.

testng.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Sample Test Suite 1">
   <parameter name="browser" value="Firefox"/>
   <parameter name="TestCaseNo" value="1"/>
     <test name="Testcase1">

      <classes>
            <class name="packagename.ABCTest">
            <methods> 
            <include name="method_A" />
            <include name="method_B" />
            <include name="method_C"/>
            <include name="method_D"/>
            </methods>
            </class>
      </classes>
        </test> 
</suite>
```

As of now, my excel utility is getting testcaseno value from testng xml and fetching data corresponding to required row.
i want to run this same testng xml for 5 testcases.

Please help me to achieve this.
Can i implement invocation count based on testcase no, as i am dependent on parameter from testng xml to get values from excel.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @Yashica...Use `@DataProvider` .. post your code so that I can tell you how to implement the same

Comment: @GauravGenius, Hi Gaurav, i am using dataprovider to get data from excel and my dataprovider is returning hashmap <key, value> where keys are headers and values are values for those labels. i.e username=abc so that user can get columnvalues based on keys name. what i want is : to run same testngxml for testcase1,2,3,4 like this.

Comment: @DataProvider(name="getdata")
 public static Object[][] getData(ITestContext context) throws Exception
 {
  HashMap<String,String> ExcelDataMap= new HashMap<String,String>();
  String TestCaseNo = context.getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("TestCaseNo");
  ExcelDataMap=hashMap.get(TestCaseNo);
  return  new Object[][]{
    {ExcelDataMap}
  };
 }
hashmap contains whole excel with keys as testcase no's and corresponding row values

Comment: i tried using dataprovider returning objects based on parameters specified in testng xml but this way @Test annotation is running based on number of objects. i want to run whole testsuite once with one paramater and then with second parameter. Can we do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is workaround to your problem, Using @DataProvider along with the @Factory annotation for creating tests at runtime..modify following things as per your need...

- Change getExcelData() method according to your requirement
- Change test methods i.e. firstTest(),secondTest()...according to requirement

This will execute whole test suite once with one parameter and then with second parameter.

**Class SomeTest**

```
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SomeTest {

    private String username;
    private String password;

    public SomeTest(String username, String password) {
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("Test #1 with data: "+username+" and "+password);
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("Test #2 with data: "+username+" and "+password);
    }

    @Test
    public void thirdTest() {
        System.out.println("Test #3 with data: "+username+" and "+password);
    }
}
```

**Class TestFactory**

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.DataProvider;
import org.testng.annotations.Factory;

public class TestFactory {

        private static FileInputStream fileInputStream;
        private static XSSFWorkbook workbook;
        private static XSSFSheet sheet;
        private static XSSFCell cell;

        @Factory(dataProvider="data")
        public Object[] createInstances(String username, String password) {
            return new Object[] {new SomeTest(username, password)};
        }

        @DataProvider(name="data")
        public Object[][] dataMethod() {
            Object[][] arrayObjects = getExcelData("C:/Eclipse/testdata.xlsx");
            return arrayObjects;    
        }

        public String[][] getExcelData(String fileName){

            String[][] arrayExcelData = null;
            try{
                fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fileName);
                workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(fileInputStream);
                sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

                int totalRows = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
                int totalCols = sheet.getRow(0).getPhysicalNumberOfCells();

                arrayExcelData = new String[totalRows-1][totalCols];
                int startRow = 1;
                int startCol = 0;

                    for(int i = startRow; i < totalRows; i++){
                        for(int j = startCol; j < totalCols; j++){
                            arrayExcelData[i-1][j] = getCellData(i,j);
                        }
                    } 
                fileInputStream.close();
            }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return arrayExcelData;
        }

        public static String getCellData(int rowNum, int colNum){
            String cellData = "";
            try{
                cell = sheet.getRow(rowNum).getCell(colNum);
                switch(cell.getCellTypeEnum()) {
                    case BOOLEAN:
                        cellData = cell.getRawValue();
                        break;
                    case NUMERIC:
                        cellData = cell.getRawValue();
                        break;
                    case STRING:
                        cellData = cell.getStringCellValue();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return cellData;
        }
    }
```

**TestFactory.xml File**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="TestFactory multiple test together" verbose="10">

  <test name="TestFactory" group-by-instances="true">
    <classes>
      <class name="com.knexuscloud.TestFactory"></class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Comment: Hi gaurav, Thanks I Tried implementing this. everything is working fine. Only question is now if i have multiple classes, it is not working. All sets of data is  running first for first class and then for second class. i want to run whole suite containing multiple classes(multiple methods) once with one set of data and then next set of data